# [Help-SQL]: i don't want the same number in cell when i am updating table column next time using Random function

Tags: sql, random, qsqlquery

I have the following query to update random number in [SetID] column.

" UPDATE Employee SET SetID = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 "
[Update Random Number query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVqL4.jpg)

But sometimes i am getting same number on a few rows after executing query. i don't want to repeat the previous number again on that row. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty ambiguous, but I don't have enough reputation to get you to clarify it...  So I am interpreting what you want is to set the SetID to a number between 1 and 5 and you don't want to use the same number as the row had before the UPDATE.  If that's the case, then this is my answer:

```
update E SET SetID = case when SetID <> r1.R1To5 then r1.R1To5
                            when SetID <> r2.R1To5 then r2.R1To5
                            when SetID <> r3.R1To5 then r3.R1To5
                            when SetID <> r4.R1To5 then r4.R1To5
                            when SetID <> r5.R1To5 then r5.R1To5
                        else case when SetID = 5 then 1
                                else SetID +1
                             end
                        end

from Employee E
cross apply  (VALUES (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 )) r1 (R1To5)
cross apply  (VALUES (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 )) r2 (R1To5)
cross apply  (VALUES (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 )) r3 (R1To5)
cross apply  (VALUES (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 )) r4 (R1To5)
cross apply  (VALUES (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 )) r5 (R1To5)
GO
```

Comment: You are genius man <3 .... exactly what i wanted, This query solved my problem :) Thank you so much bro.